# lerna import always returns EDESTDIR

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, lerna

I have a pre-existing project that I'd like to import into my existing lerna monorepo that uses yarn workspaces.

#### Command(s):

> I've tried running all of the following commands. The error remains stubbornly unchanged. Also, petstore has a package.json file and is a git repo.

```
lerna import ./petstore --dest="./packages/"
lerna import ./petstore --dest="./packages/api/"
```

### ERROR:

```
lerna notice cli v3.20.2
lerna ERR! EDESTDIR --dest does not match with the package directories: packages/**
```

> Also, `lerna import ../petstore` results in a `packages/**/petstore` being created which is not an expected result.

I hope this consists of all the relevant code. We have supporting packages under `packages/shared` and apis under `packages/api`.

#### lerna.json

```
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/**/*"
  ],
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "useWorkspaces": true,
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "lerna": "2.11.0"
}
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^2.11.0"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/**/*"
  ],
}
```

#### Resources I have looked at:

- 
- [Lerna troubleshooting page](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/master/doc/troubleshooting.md) but it does not have any info on this error.
- [Lerna Github Issue #1872](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1872)
- [Lerna Github Issue #1197](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1197)
- [Lerna Slack Link Broken](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1404)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lerna reads the packages from the key `workspaces` on package.json instead of the `packages` on lerna.json.

lerna reads all the values with a `/*` and considers them package directories. It interprets `**` literally and does not parse it as a wildcard and expand it.

The solution is to remove `packages` from `lerna.json`:

```
{
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "useWorkspaces": true,
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "lerna": "2.11.0"
}
```

and update the workspaces path to refer to any sub-directories in your packages explicitly if your monorepo is structured that way:

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^2.11.0"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/a/*",
    "packages/api/*"
  ],
}
```

To import the `pet-store` project into `packages/api` in the monorepo from a directory outside the mono-repo:

```
lerna import ../pet-store --dest="./packages/api/"
```