# lerna ERR! EDESTDIR --dest does not match with the package directories: packages

Tags: lerna, monorepo

When trying to import a repo into my lerna monorepo it keeps failing with:

`lerna ERR! EDESTDIR --dest does not match with the package directories: packages`

I'm using the default lerna.json config.

```
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*",
  ],
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

The import command I'm using is:

`npx lerna import --flatten /Users/home/Desktop/Lerna_Tests/docs-repo --dest=docs`

I also tried:

`npx lerna import --flatten /Users/home/Desktop/Lerna_Tests/docs-repo --dest=packages/docs`

However, both fail with the same error.

I want the repo to go to the packages/docs directory.

Answer (score 2):

### Summary

I added a directory glob entry to my lerna.json packages array and added quotes to my import command to fix it.

### Explanation:

I realized that when setting up the lerna.json I was using the default lerna.json config but needed to add an entry to the packages array like this:

```
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*",
    "packages/docs/*" <<<<<<<<< I added this line.
  ],
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

> NOTE: the /* is important after the directory.

Once I added this, the following command imported my repository without a problem:

`npx lerna import --flatten /Users/home/Desktop/Lerna_Tests/docs-repo --dest="packages/docs"`

> Note: I tried without the quotes around the destination directory and it didn't work for some reason. The docs for Lerna give an example without using quotes so I assume that it must be okay in some circumstances just not in mine.

[This SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60254487/lerna-import-always-returns-edestdir) helped my fix my error. However, it was a different solution and a different problem so I thought I'd post my question answer for those whose issue relates closer to the above situation.

Comment: This worked for me thanks, also need to make sure there are no uncommitted changes before importing (still lerning)